# Window.location doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect after my ajax call return succeed. I tried  `window.location`, `window.location.href`, `self.location` but page doesn't redirect to target page. Here is my all ajax post codes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_Yeni', function (event) {
var date= $("#deSeansTarihi").val();
var _iHastaId= $("#hdnHastaId").val();

date= date.toString().substring(3, 5) + "." + date.toString().substring(0, 2) + "." + date.toString().substring(6, 10);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "KlinikHastalari.aspx/SetNewData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ _dtTarih: date, _id: _iHastaId}),
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        window.location("http://localhost:59508/trunk/abs.aspx?hid=" + _iHastaId);
    }
});
```

});

SetNewData function returns succeed. What should I do to redirect target page?

Comment: Put the code in jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) works just fine. The problem is you're treating it like a function. It isn't a function, you just assign to it:

```
window.location = "http://localhost:59508/trunk/abs.aspx?hid=" + _iHastaId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are using jQuery Mobile in your code. 
Therefore you could also use `$.mobile.changePage` to redirect to a new page.
Check the reference here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Comment: What makes you think it's jQuery Mobile as opposed to simply jQuery?